# Compiling classes with Toolprovider and loading them with ClassLoader

Tags: java, classloader, urlclassloader

I'm trying to load classes that I generate an compile in runtime. I can compile them without no problem with this code:

```
JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
StandardJavaFileManager fileManager = compiler.getStandardFileManager(null, null, null);

List<File> sourceFileList = new ArrayList<File>();
sourceFileList.add(new File(sourceFile));
Iterable<? extends JavaFileObject> compilationUnits = fileManager.getJavaFileObjectsFromFiles(sourceFileList);
CompilationTask task = compiler.getTask(null, fileManager, null, null,null, compilationUnits);
```

But I don't understand how to load the Class I've compiled (or where it is compiled) for posterior usage. I've tried several things like:

```
Class type = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().loadClass(className);
```

or

```
ClassLoader loader = URLClassLoader.newInstance(new URL[] { myUrl }, getClass().getClassLoader());  //(URL?)
```

without success (I don't understand these...). Could you help me or give a simple example of ho to do this so I can develop form it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you pass the correct path of the class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last attempt should work. `myUrl` should refer to the directory (or Jar) containing the .class generated.

```
myUrl = new URL("file:///myGeneratedCode/");
```

The url must end with a `"/"` to be considered a directory, otherwise, it will assume a Jar file.

Comment: Ok, thanks. But I don't know why when after executing 'task.call()' no class is generated anywhere and neither any error is reported in console or using Diagnostic.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the 'problem'. It was a stupid mistake from my side: I was trying to compile the generated java file before closing it. The annoying thing it's that JavaCompiler was not throwing any Exception.

With this solved and the class generated I have no more issues loading it with ClassLoader

Thanks again.